# Is there a way to create pages/activities or something similar based on a users input?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to ask a user how many times a week they go to the gym, and depending on their input i want to display "x" amount of activites one after the other.

Example: User inputs 4 days a week. following that, the next activity will be a page for day one, then they click a button, then day 2, then click a button, then day 3 and so on.

One way I thought of doing this is creating 7 activities for the 7 days of the week, but id like to find a better way.

Another way which I'm not sure if its possible, is to create a sort of recursive Activity.

Example: User inputs 4 days a week. following that, the next activity will be a page for day one, then they click a button which opens up the same activity but with all the data they put in previously saved in a DB, and the inputs for day 1 has been cleared, so it becomes day 2.

if any one has any knowledge on the above scenario if you have done something similar or know if android studio has a better way to do this, any input will be appreciated, still a beginner using android studio, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create just different views in Android Studio ? Creating 7 different views would be the easy way, but if you want to do it more elegantly you could create one "template view". So you create a file/view with some placeholders like "Activity" and "Day_X". Then for every page the user can get to, you open up the same view (page, mask) but fill it with different data.
Then you can just based on the user input code something like:
"Create me NUM_DAYS_USER_INPUT times the activity template mask", once with the data for activity one, once with the data for activity too and so on...
You just need to pass the correct data for the single views to the masks.